# Stock Images - Modern Experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages

Is there a way I can directly access the stock images from a link, rather than from adding an image webpart on a modern experience to show the images ?

One of a site collection is still in Classic UI and I would like to access the stock images from there.

I know user would need to right click on any image and copy the image address.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No. The stock images is only available when adding an image to a modern SharePoint page.

The SharePoint stock images is a new feature which is published in April (MC210572). You could check this infomation in the Message center:

[image]